# How do I POST JSON data object to server iOS8?

Tags: objective-c, json

I want to send a new object created on iOS to a receiving server with a POST method using JSON data type. From what I know about receiving data from the server in iOS, is that all JSON handling was simplified by Apple with the introduction of iOS 8. But in contradistinction to GETting JSON objects, POSTing those isn't really described anywhere I could find ...

The first steps I took to try and solve the problem looked as follows:

How can I send the below format to server???

```
 {"createFrom":"","createType":"","filename":"AC","filter":"","lstData":[{"FieldName":"LNK_RELATED_CN","FieldValue":""},{"FieldName":"LNK_RELATED_CO","FieldValue":""},{"FieldName":"MLS_PURPOSE","FieldValue":"Inquiry"},{"FieldName":"MLS_STATUS","FieldValue":"Open"},{"FieldName":"MMO_NOTES","FieldValue":""},{"FieldName":"DTE_NEXTACTIONDATE","FieldValue":""},{"FieldName":"MMO_NEXTACTION","FieldValue":""}],"password":"Infodat2","username":"manmeets","IsNew":true}
```

I have seen code like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@AssetSave",[defaults objectForKey:@"siteAddress"]]];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
_responseData = [NSMutableData data];
NSLog(@"request : %@", request);
_nsurlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

But I really don't know how to send a JSON object to a server using a POST method at all. Could anybody please help me out?

Comment: The code you show does what you want if you create the `jsonData`

Comment: how can i send the above json format to the server? using POST

Comment: You have a JSON string, or an object graph (array or dictionary)?

Comment: I have to send complete JSON String

Comment: But what do you have? You have a string? Where did it come from?

Comment: I want to send the server to same format, field names and field values are object keys and values.  Actually the above json string is Android developers send the date to server same format. but in iOS how to send the data to server same format using post method.

Comment: Im sending the data to server below format :  NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    
    [dict setValue:lastNameStr forKey:@"TXT_NAMELAST"];
    [dict setValue:FN forKey:@"TXT_NAMELAST"];
    [dict setValue:companyGID_ID forKey:@"LNK_RELATED_CO"]; NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [arr addObject:dict];
    NSMutableDictionary *serverDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [serverDict setValue:@"" forKey:@"createFrom"];
    [serverDict setValue:@"" forKey:@"createType"];
    [serverDict setValue:arr forKey:@"lstData"];

Answer (score 1):

The code you have is fine, you just need to create `jsonData`:

```
jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:nil];
```

(thought you should really also include an `&error` so you can see what's happening if something goes wrong)